# GCP - Unable to authenticate myself to invoke Google Cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I have a cloud function named `rad_format_text_v0`. I (andy@onehot.io) have permission to invoke it, shown here:

```
$ gcloud beta functions get-iam-policy rad_format_text_v0
bindings:
- members:
  - allAuthenticatedUsers
  - user:andy@onehot.io
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
etag: BwWOSfjYxp0=
version: 1
```

I can invoke it using `gcloud functions call`...

```
$ gcloud auth list
           Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE             ACCOUNT
*                  andy@onehot.io

$ gcloud functions call rad_format_text_v0 --data "$(< test.json)"
executionId: 2wm7nrgc0vjo
result: |
  ["REDACTED successful result"]
```

However, when I try another HTTP client like `curl`, it fails even though I'm passing an auth token...

```
$ curl -i -X POST "https://us-central1-onehot-autocoder.cloudfunctions.net/rad_format_text_v0" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" --data @test.json
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2019 19:46:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 312
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/rad_format_text_v0</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I did exactly as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers). I have no idea why my token is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` to get the token and the documentation you shared specify that you should use the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command instead.

I tested it and I found that I was not able to use the `print-identity-token` for my user account. Instead I had to [create a new service account and activate it](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started). Then in the curl command, I specified the service account like in the example below:

```
curl -i https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME] -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token [SERVICE_ACCOUNT] )"
```

Apparently the Google Cloud SDK has an issue with the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command on version 254, you could also try to downgrade it with the following command:

```
gcloud components update --version 249.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Funnily enough, _today_ Google released gcloud 255.0.0 and `gcloud auth print-identity-token` now works exactly as advertised.