# GCP - unable to print identity token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to get a JWT for my personal account but this command errors out:

```
$ gcloud auth print-identity-token
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) `--audiences` can only be specified for service account.
```

It's complaining that I can't supply the `--audiences` option, but I didn't provide that. According to [their docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers), I'm supposed to be able to use this command while signed in to my individual developer account.

Edit: I'm using Google Cloud SDK version 254.0.0

Update: JUST NOW Google released gcloud version 255.0.0 and the command works exactly as advertised with an individual account.

Comment: What version of the Google Cloud SDK are you using? Check by running `gcloud info`.

Comment: `Google Cloud SDK [254.0.0]`

Comment: With version 255 you still should not use User Credentials with the CLI. Any programs that you write that use Application Default Credentials will report a big warning message (except for service account credentials) and your API calls will be limited (which is part of the message).

Comment: From the actual Google source code: Credentials from the Cloud SDK that are associated with Cloud SDK's project are problematic because they may not have APIs enabled and have limited quota. If this is the case, warn about it. https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/auth/_default.html

Comment: This is one of the messages that will be printed: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are receiving is correct. Trying to modify Google OAuth User Credentials for a "gmail" type of account with `claims` is not supported. Audience `aud` is a claim specified when a JWT is created.

If you are using Identity Platform, you can to a limited degree.

You cannot modify User Credentials with claims, but you can specify certain claims when requesting a service account Identity Token.

Execute the following command `gcloud auth list`. If the active account is an email address and not a service account email address, you will get this error.

Comment: While your answer makes sense to me, it seems to contradict [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers). They are using this command in their tutorial on authenticating _developers_, i.e. treated as end-user requests. So, it seems it's _supposed_ to work for non-service account email addresses. Are the docs just wrong?

Comment: Can you show me where (exactly)? This is an area that I know very well and spend a lot of time in. I will be very happy to improve my answer if you can show me where you can apply claims when requesting OAuth User Credentials. If this is the case, I can make a request to improve the documentation which is always welcome.

Comment: Under the heading "Developers". It says, "When using curl or similar tools, you must treat these as end-user requests." Then, it shows a snippet how to authenticate as a developer: `curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`

Comment: Incidentally, I found the solution within an answer to a _different_ question I posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152969/gcp-unable-to-authenticate-myself-to-invoke-google-cloud-function). If I roll back to gcloud version 249, `print-identity-token` command works for me.

Comment: Yes, that command will work, but you will get warnings from Google about using User Credentials instead of a Service Account and you will be rate-limited (e.g. the command will stop working after N requests). However, the issue that you are stating is "custom claims" (audience) and that is not the same thing as what you found.

Comment: That's all fine. I never wanted to set a "custom claim". In prod I'll use a service account, but I'm just testing. I posted because the error is telling me I'm not allowed to provide `--audiences` when I never attempted to add that in the first place. I just wanted to follow the instructions in the documentation and get a token to authenticate myself to the cloud function.

Comment: Back in a circle we go, to use `gcloud auth print-identity-token` you need to configure gcloud with a service account. You have configured gcloud with User Credentials which is NOT recommended by Google Cloud for anything - think legacy services. Note: be careful with old versions. A number of Google services are being updated right now to support Identity Tokens. In some cases, newer command-line options (example Cloud Run) are now mandatory else the command will fail. This mostly affects beta services but they are rapidly becoming GA.

Comment: My issue had more to do with the fact that the docs says it works but in reality it doesn't (in the latest version of gcloud anyways). If it's in the docs, it should work. That page doesn't say to do it with a service account. It says that _developers_ can authenticate themselves to CFs so I performed the method as they described. No mention of requiring service accounts in that section. They should either make it work as advertised or change the docs.

Comment: Nonetheless, the state of the documentation is not our faults. You've provided me with much helpful information and I understand the issue because of your efforts. Thank you!